# "Featured" font very small in jobs - remove property

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The text `featured` on a specific job is hard to read and seems scrunched together:

[image]

If we remove the `font-size` property it's much more readable and cleaner, besides we are **featuring** a job, it only makes sense to have it stand out:

[image]